# Opening the links of every google search results python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#number of pages, atm i set it to cycle through 5 pages, starting page is 0
max_page = 5

#number of digits (ie: 2 is 1 digit, 10 is 2 digits, increase when appropriate)
max_dig = 1

#Open up firefox browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#search results "acoustics+companies+in+us"
question = input("\nWhat would you like to google today, but replace every space with a '+' (ie: am+i+a+good+carry)\n\n")

search = []    

#get multiple pages
for i in range(0, max_page + 1):
    page_num = (max_dig - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    #inserts search input and cycles through pages
    url =  "https://www.google.com/search?q="+ question +"&ei=LV-uXYrpNoj0rAGC8KSYCg&start="+ page_num +"0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjKs8ie367lAhUIOisKHQI4CaM4ChDy0wMIiQE&biw=1356&bih=946"
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "LC20lb")))
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('LC20lb')
    for element in elements:
        search.append(element.text)

    #finds the links of the google search, holds down command and clicks the link to open the links in a new tab
    links = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
    ActionChains(driver)
    .key_down(Keys.COMMAND)
    .click(links)
    .perform()

for item in search:
    print(item)
```

I've made a web scraper that can print the title of the search results of multiple google search pages (ie: Python - Wikipedia). I would like to be able to open the page of all the search results in a new tab while it prints the results and goes through every page.

Comment: You should use `BeautifulSoup` and `webbrowser` modules for this

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to integrate both selenium and BS or would I have to use one or the other

Comment: Do you want to actually open the page in the firefox browser?

Comment: Not necessarily open it in a Firefox browser, but I do want to retrieve specific information from the pages, whichever way possible.

Comment: Like the links?

Comment: Well, more like the contact details which can be found inside the website.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is best suited for this

Comment: Read this- https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: I'm able to use both Beautiful soup and Selenium together right? Or do I have to recode everything using beautiful soup only

Comment: You'll probably have to use only BS, but that shouldn't be a problem. It's rather simple

Comment: If my application for it is to scrape the titles of multiple Google search results and the contact detail of each of the pages that the results gives, Beautiful soup does that right? Just checking since I want to clarify if not I may end up passing my deadline

Comment: How do you intend to find the contact number?

Comment: So the idea is that once it does a Google search, it'll enter the page that google links. Then it'll try to find the "About us" or "Contact" button within the page. Once it access either of the two pages, it'll look for the contacts.